# Will the new version of my app recognize old IAPs?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

This is hopefully a simple question:

I have an approved iOS app with in app purchases, and I'm trying to update a new version. Can I leave the in app purchases section of the iTunes Connect submission process blank, and just assume that the new version will refer to the already approved IAPs, or do I need to create a new set of purchases for the new app version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He existing purchases should still be available, but you should also test this by running the TestFlight version of the app before you submit it. You can also view the App Store configuration section in iTunes connect to review what's there and see if you need to make any changes. Make sure they're all still marked and flagged as ready for sale.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I assumed, but assuming that iTunesConnect will do sensible things has bitten me in the past.